# Grid Row color Change on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to change the row color on select of a row but after that, I cannot reset the previous color of the other row. I am using a jQuery function.

Note: all rows in this grid have an alternating color system.

**Javascript code:**

```
function ChangeRowColor(rowID) {
    $('#' + rowID).removeClass('DataRow');
    $('#' + rowID).addClass('DataRow1');
}
```

Comment: this might be helpful: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sapnabeniwal/animate-and-highlight-gridview-rows-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the original class

```
function ChangeRowColor(rowID) {
    $('tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('tr#' + rowID).addClass('highlighted');
}
```

Give the class `.highlighted` all changes, remove it from all rows and add it to the single row you want.